# Give a class its own `self` at instantiation time?

Tags: python, class, instantiation, self

I've got a button class that you can instantiate like so:

```
engine.createElement((0, 0), Button(code=print, args=("Stuff!",)))
```

And when it is clicked it will print "Stuff!". However, I need the button to destroy itself whenever it is clicked. Something like this:

```
engine.createElement((0, 0), Button(code=engine.killElement, args=(self,)))
```

However, that would just kill the caller, because self refers to the caller at that moment. What I need to do is give the class its own 'self' in advance...

I thought of just making the string `'self'` refer to the `self` variable upon click, but what if I wanted to use the string `'self'` in the arguments?

What is the way to do this? Is my architecture all wrong or something?

Comment: Are you asking how to design the API for your Button Class?  Or are you asking about a specific Button class which presumably exists in some external module?

Comment: @mgilson I'm looking for a non hacky way to pass the new class's self to itself. I figured there was some sort of special syntax to do it or something.

Comment: No special syntax exists for that unless the class itself provides that functionality via some special constant.  And there's no standard idiom that people use for this as far as I know.

Comment: I assume you mean the new _instance's_ self to itself, not the new _class_, right?

Comment: Most APIs use a signal mechanism and a callback. Your callback can be a bound object that has access to the button's container, and then remove the button instance it gets from the container.

Comment: @abarnert That's right. Sorry for the clumsy wording.

Comment: Button is a class and presumably has some method which is called when it's clicked. In order to call the method, the corresponding Button instance must have been identified and will be used to call the method. The first argument the method will receive will be the button instance -- so it seems like a non-problem...

Comment: @martineau Yes, but the button is supposed to perform a callback whenever it is clicked. The callback in this case is `killElement`, which destroys whatever it is passed. The arguments I'm trying to give it is itself, so it will destroy itself when cilcked.

Comment: You say you need "give the class its own 'self' in advance". Give what class what 'self'?

Comment: @martineau I'm creating a button that needs to kill itself upon click. I need to give the new button its own self on instantiation, before it is created.

Comment: Ah, so basically you want to pass a constructor call the instance it returns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in general.

However, if you're creating the `Button` class, you can pass a special sentinel value that means "yourself". For example:

```
class Button(object):
    yourself = 'yourself'
    def __init__(self, code, args):
        self.code = code
        self.args = [self if arg is yourself else arg for arg in args]
```

Then:

```
engine.createElement((0, 0), Button(code=engine.killElement, args=(Button.yourself,)))
```

Picking an appropriate sentinel can be tricky—obvious choices like `None`, `0`, or `''` may be legitimate values, and even tricky things you come up with may turn out to be useful arguments during debugging. Making `yourself` a class variable, or a global within the module, means that if you ever do need to redefine the sentinel, you only need to change it in one place, instead of everywhere you use it.

See http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/555169-sentinel-values-special-cases for a brief discussion on picking an appropriate sentinel value. There's another blog out there with more information, but I haven't found it in a quick search… Anyway, here are some quick ideas:

1. `None` is always the best answer if it works.
2. Define an empty class to be the sentinel. Either the class object, or any instance of the class object, can be used.
3. Create a global instance of the `object` class (`object()`).
4. Define an empty function and use it (or its `func_code` or whatever).
5. `Ellipsis` (or `type(Ellipsis)`, which is a type named `ellipsis`, but that name isn't accessible) is almost always safe, because it's only used in `__getitem__` and friends (and possibly in defining `slice` objects to pass to them).
6. If there's a type that could not possibly be a valid value, and you've already got instances around, use one of those—e.g., the `func_code` member of the `__init__` function.

Comment: What would the sentinel value be? Some kind of string would be the most logical solution, but then I can't use that value if I wanted to.

Comment: Updated the answer to deal with the sentinel question… but give me a sec and I'll search for a blog post on the issue that I read once.

Comment: `Ellipsis` makes a good sentinel where `None` is a valid value. The only real use of `Ellipsis` is in a `__getitem__()` method.

Comment: @kindall: Yeah, that usually works… but I'm not sure it's any more readable than a specially-defined class or function, or any of the other options. (That's why I suggested giving whatever you use a name as a module or class variable.) Anyway, I'll add it to the list.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is impossible — the arguments to the button's constructor are evaluated before the constructor is evaluated. You'd need to assign the button to a variable, then set the callback afterwards:

```
b = Button(code=engine.killElement)
b.args = (b, )
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You've essentially set it up so that you need a reference to an object in order to create that object, which is of course impossible. You could do something like this (a list is as good as a tuple for argument unpacking):

```
arglist = []
button = Button(code=engine.killElement, args=arglist)
arglist.append(button)
engine.createElement((0, 0), button)
```

This is inelegant, unclear, and verbose, but it'll get the reference to the instance into the instance.

You could use a sentinel value as another poster suggested. Perhaps a better suggestion would be to simply use a convention (like Python itself) that `self` is always passed as the first argument to the specified function and doesn't need to be specified explicitly. Then your callbacks are written to always take `self`, even if they don't do anything with it.

But generally you would not specify an object's behavior by passing it to that object's constructor, but through inheritance. In other words you'd *subclass* `Button`, override its `onClick` method or whatever, and instantiate the subclass. Having `onClick` know what instance it's attached to is a non-issue. So I come down on the side of yes, your architecture is a wee bit all wrong.

Comment: I was contemplating a convoluted `lambda` function doing essentially the same thing.  This is slightly better than what I was dreaming up.  +1

Comment: +1. But this only works if `Button.__init__` does something like `self.args = args` and then calls `code(*args)`. What if it makes a copy of args, or makes a C++/ObjC/whatever vector out of the args to pass to Qt/Win32/Cocoa/whatever? So, you do need to know your windowing library to know if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
class Button(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['args'].append(obj)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, code, args):
        self.code = code
        self.args = args

    def click(self):
        return self.code, self.args

b = Button(code="engine.killElement", args=[])
print b.click()
```

Output:

```
('engine.killElement', [<__main__.Button object at 0x00B59AF0>])
```

Comment: This is a clever trick… but couldn't you achieve the exact same thing just by doing `self.args = args + [self]` in the `__init__`?

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, good point. Only advantage might be that it could easily be made a base class to derive other widget from to automatically have them inherit the behavior.